# HornetQ Memory Usage

Tags: performance, memory, hornetq

We're using horetq-core-client 2.4.0.Final, embedded, and sending String message about 300 chars in size. If we don't dequeue message, what happens to the memory usage of hornetq? Is it capped at some point and future sends to the queue, the journal will just continue to grow in size (and not heap)? Is there a way to tune the memory usage for cases where there may be a period of messages not being consumed so we don't get out of memory errors?

Comment: Please don't cross post hornetq questions on SOF and HornetQ user's forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at paging. You can configure paging and make the disk grow.

There are some considerations on the user manual..

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/index.html#paging

Comment: I'm using a maxSizeBytes=104857600, pageSizeBytes=10485760, and pageCacheMaxSize=10, and addressFullMessagePolicy=PAGE. Does this seem reasonable? Memory looks stable, but have not tested yet to see what happens if I stop dequeueing messages.